# convert string array to float array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, floating-point, double

We are getting an error when trying to run this code ideally changes  `e.Message` from `string` to a `double` or `float array`. Please help us understand what the error means, or how to debug the code.

We also tired a `float.Parse(e.Message, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);` method, which also resulted in an error.

```
private void ClientReceiveData(object sender, ConnectedClient.NetDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
    {
        if (e.ID == 0)
        {
            //float.Parse(e.Message, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(','), Double.Parse);
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Message));
        }

        if (e.ID == 1)
        {
            //float.Parse(e.Message, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(','), Double.Parse);
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Message));
        }
    }
```

**INPUT** (e.Message):

```
0.0160163, -0.3207418, -0.2747217, 0.9856872, -0.3428816, 0.02380935, 0.8472792, -0.3562718, 0.3080477, 0.6931204, -0.4135765, 0.2335226, 0.6617407, -0.2861188, 0.278595, 0.685502, -0.3337714, 0.06315409, 0.5661756, -0.5338272, 0.1274863, 0.6014508, -0.6020046, 0.149146, 0.6165056, -0.2287867, 0.108688, 0.753313, -0.2801398, 0.1555204, 0.5711947, -0.4046459, 0.3197014, 0.6477473, -0.4134837, 0.3147845, 0.6426268, -0.3393434, -0.242843, 0.9667573, -0.3945386, -0.2511228, 0.5462032, -0.4459318, -0.2613428, 0.2010812, -0.43355, -0.2804166, 0.09203719, -0.2818186, -0.2890762, 0.9426621, -0.2850094, -0.2625419, 0.5789056, -0.2990395, -0.2414854, 0.1805503, -0.2872439, -0.2554213, 0.06843466, -0.3543724, 0.2399589, 0.7335942, -0.5984071, 0.1476627, 0.6094998, -0.5848852, 0.1458522, 0.6007382, -0.4560334, 0.3629844, 0.6141819, -0.4130909, 0.2523528, 0.57725,
```

[image: error]

Comment: We need a [MCVE] included _in your question_.  Include your actual input, not a screenshot from your IDE

Comment: Paste the entire contents of `e.Message` as plain text.  There is something in there it doesn't like, and we can't see the entire thing.

Comment: Thanks for relpying @maccettura. the input is actually a string of decimal numbers coming from 2 client computers to this third server computer via a TCPIP connection. Its the coordinates of an individuals Joints using a KinectV2. So the actual input is for ex: 1.1564, 0.5361, .. -1.1564. Anything specific you would like me to provide?

Comment: @JayTailor we need an example of the _actual_ input.  As Paul said there is something wrong with the input and we need to see it

Comment: BTW, `ConvertAll` returns a new array so if you don't assign the output to anything it won't be very useful.

Comment: I have included the full input in the updated original question

Comment: You have a trailing comma, which is resulting in a blank entry from `split`.  Use the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option.  This is a good example of why we discourage screenshots of error messages.

Comment: @JayTailor The trailing comment is likely the problem, add the option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: Ya I added that and it works now! Thank you all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last entry is an empty string which will not parse with `Double.Parse`.

You may use:

```
var parsed = Array.ConvertAll(
    e.Message.Split(new[] { ',', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
    Double.Parse);
```

Also note that `Double.Parse` depends on the current `CultureInfo` for the interpretation of periods `.` in the strings.

Comment: That depends. If the event handling method needs to run twice before you can find the "vector sum" `final`, you may have `double[] answer;` and `double[] result;` as __fields__ (i.e. variable on the class-level, outside methods). Then you can calculate `final` from that after both fields have been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to catch the offending value, and should ignore "empty" entries like the one created by the trailing comma:

```
private void ClientReceiveData(object sender, ConnectedClient.NetDataEventArgs e)
{
    double[] result = null; 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
    {
        if (e.ID == 0)
        {
            //float.Parse(e.Message, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            result = Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), ParseWithError);
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Message));
        }

        if (e.ID == 1)
        {
            //float.Parse(e.Message, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
            result = Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split( new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), ParseWithError);
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Message));
        }
    }
}

double ParseWithError(string value) 
{
     double result;
     if (!double.TryParse(value, out result))
     {
         throw new ApplicationException("Error parsing value " + value,e);
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: More nice in my opinion: `double ParseWithError(string value) 
{
    if (double.TryParse(value, out var dbl)) { return dbl; } throw new ApplicationException("Error parsing value " + value); }`